# Solve $(e^{2 \pi ix}-1)u'=0$ in $D'(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, distribution-theory

I'm trying to solve the following problems in the sense of distributions Q8c of example sheet 1 of the Distribution Theory course of part III of the mathematical tripos.

$(e^{2 \pi ix}-1)u'=0$.

In order to solve this problem, I tried working backwards. Take a $\psi \in D(\mathbb{R})$. I want to construct a $\phi \in D(\mathbb{R})$ such that
$$
\langle u,\psi \rangle = \langle u,-\frac{\phi}{e^{2 \pi ix}-1} \rangle
= \langle (e^{2 \pi ix}-1)u',\phi \rangle
=0.
$$

My issue is that such a $\phi$ satisfies $\phi(x)=\frac{{ \int_{0}^{x} \psi(y)dy}}{1-e^{2 \pi ix}}$ for $x \neq 0$. This would cause $\phi$ to be undefined on $\mathbb{Z}$.

I'm slightly stuck here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The pdf says "Copyright © 2020 University of Cambridge. Not to be quoted or reproduced without permission." I'm not sure it can be linked here.

Comment: I very happily acknowledge my mistake and have removed the link. I would really appreciate it if we could move our discussion back to mathematics.

Comment: Try starting with proving that for a distribution $u$ such that $f\cdot u=0$ for a smooth function $f$, then the support of $u$ is contained in the $0$-set of $f$. (Further, if the zeros $z_o$ are simple, in the sense that $f'(z_o)\not=0$, then $u$ is a (possibly infinite) linear combination of Dirac deltas at those zeros.)